# Alternate of System.Uri.UnescapeDataString in SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with one column named CustomField1. I have a following data in it:-

```
%20%2203004234272%22%3Csip.
```

It was actually  `"03004234272"<sip`.

`%20` for a space in start.

I have used a following function to convert this string.

```
public static string ToJavaScriptString(string input)
{
    return Uri.EscapeDataString(input).Replace("'", @"\'").Replace(@"""", @"\""");
}
```

In SQL Query I am trying to get all those rows where `CustomField1` contains `20`.

Any ideas how can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'd suggest not storing url encoded data in the database.

Comment: Cant change a logic. @mjwills

Comment: Why can't you change that logic? Honestly - asking a database to url decode data is going to be **painful**. Your ability to use index lookups, as an example, is gone.

Comment: Beacuse this piece of shit was not written by me and now customers have enough data. Actually this was written by another library.

Comment: Maybe you could add an extra column, maybe a virtual/calculated column with the correct data. That way, both the encoded and the normal version are available, but you can also have an index on both. But then again, a 'contains' query doesn't use indexes anyway, and you'd still need a stored proc to decode the data to be able to create a virtual column.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yeah looking into it how to decode it. I was thinking may be it was much easier and I am missing any thing.